# How to update UI from backbone cached response in titanium

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, titanium, titanium-alloy

I am trying to introduce cache to backbone fetch function in Titanium alloy. I have managed to cache the response and fetch the object back from cache but still did not succeed on the Backbone side of updating the UI without doing a request to the API.

I was able to replicate behavior on a web browser but seems like things differ a bit on Titanium Alloy.

Here is the code for my collection/model, precisley when **if(resp)** is valid

```
exports.definition = {
config: {
    "URL": "http://example.com/best-sellers/",
    "adapter": {
        "type": "restapi",
        "collection_name": "best_sellers", 
        "idAttribute": "id"
    },
    "headers": { 
        "Accept": "application/json"
    },
},      
extendModel: function(Model) {      
    _.extend(Model.prototype, {});
    return Model;
},
extendCollection: function(Collection) {
    _.extend(Collection.prototype, {
        initialize: function() {
            this.cacheKey = "bestSellers";
            this.cacheTimeout = 1200;
        },
        fetch: function(options) {
            // Fetch resp from cache
            var resp = Ti.App.Cache.get(this.cacheKey);

            // Check if cache was not empty
            if (resp) {
                // Options if not set
                options = options || {};
                // Copy success method
                var success = options.success;

                options = _.extend({parse: true}, options);

                var collection = this;
                options.success = function(resp) {
                    var method = options.reset ? 'reset' : 'set';
                    collection['reset'](resp, options);
                    if (success) success.call(options.context, collection, resp, options);
                    collection.trigger('sync', collection, resp, options);
                };
                // ---> What should I be calling here to update the UI without doing a request to the API
            } else {

                // The cache object doesn't hold the required data
                // Preparing success method that set the cache 
                var success = options.success || function() {};
                var that = this;
                options.success = function(entity, resp, options) {
                    Ti.App.Cache.put(that.cacheKey, resp, this.cacheTimeout);
                    if (success) success(entity, resp, options);
                };
                // Calling the original fetch
                return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
            }
        }
    });
    return Collection;
}
```

};

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [backbone.js cache collections and refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991484/backbone-js-cache-collections-and-refresh)